# How to do Animation like BooK front cover in iOS?

Tags: ios, animation, page-curl

I want the Page flip animation for Photo Album Book cover even though I have added animation for pages (Used UIpageViewController) but need to have main page animation as well.

Please see [this link](http://pageflip.hu/#demo1/page/Cover), exactly like this I want.

Comment: update:-Please help me to achieve the animation like in above given link.In that link, For inner pages i have done, for book cover(front and back animation) i need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code , after long hours work I solved this task , feeling happy :)
Updated:

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView commitAnimations];
CATransform3D initialTransform = ges.view.layer.transform;
initialTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -1100;
layer.transform = initialTransform;
layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(-0.0, 0.5);
NSLog(@"%f %f",layer.frame.origin.x,layer.frame.origin.y);
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Scale" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = ges.view.layer.transform;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, M_PI , 0 , -ges.view.bounds.size.height/2, 0);
layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView commitAnimations];

[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: yes, for animation part.rotating view is album front cover only which flip from left to right , is what i wanted.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but may I ask how you implemented this with the UIPageViewController?

Answer (score 3):

Check this :

http://code4app.net/ios/Flip-Transform-View/4f75aa156803faa60f000000

Go through the video given for the code reference.

I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: actually i have implemented the UIpageViewcontroller and now I want to add the Cover to that.so that is i am looking for.

Comment: Then keen this two animations seperated. For first page (cover page) use the flip transform and for the other use UIPageViewController.

Comment: Please check my answer.I achieved it.