# iOS - UIPageViewControllerDataSource method called twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I found a weird issue with the two `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` methods: the first time I enter the page view controller scene and drag on the content of the controller, no matter what the dragging direction is, both of the data source methods get called. I suppose that when I'm at the first page and drag to the right, which means that there is no more page before the first page, neither of the methods should get called. And if I drag to the left, only the after method should get called.

I followed [this post](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) to set up the view controllers (except that I do not have a separate page view controller on the storyboard. I used the traditional `[UIPAgeViewController alloc] init]` method to instantiate the controller). Below is my code:

For the view controller that actually displays the content of the page view controller (only the relevant part of `viewDidLoad` is shown):

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    // initialize page view controller
    _pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    // set up the initial scene of the page view controller
    UIViewController *viewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[viewController]
                                      direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                       animated:NO
                                     completion:nil];

    // adjust the size of the page view controller, -44 to show the buttons at the bottom
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 44);

    // display the content of the page view controller
    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
      viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PWCPageContentViewController *)viewController).index;
    if (index == 0 || index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }
    --index;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
       viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PWCPageContentViewController *)viewController).index;
    if (index == self.numberOfPages - 1 || index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }
    ++index;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (PWCPageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    PWCPageContentViewController *viewController =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
    viewController.index = index;
    NSString *text = [self.notes getNoteAtIndex:index];
    [viewController.textView setText:text];

    return viewController;
}
```

For PWCPageContentViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class PWCNotes;

@interface PWCPageContentViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>

@property NSUInteger index;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

- (void)dismissKeyboard;

@end
```

For PWCPageContentViewController.m:

```
#import "PWCPageContentViewController.h"

@interface PWCPageContentViewController ()

@end

@implementation PWCPageContentViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.textView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dismissKeyboard
{
    if ([self.textView isFirstResponder]) {
        // dismiss the keyboard when hitting save
        [self.textView resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

@end
```

So is this a known issue or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIPageViewController` uses these bellow method for getting the back and front ViewController.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

Though its weird but yes its a known issue. Every time it calls Before and After method to get VC. If there is no next VC then it returns `nil` and if there is no previous VC the `datasourceDelegate` return nil, otherwise it return the index of VC.

In `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`, there is a function named :

```
 - (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers;
```

Look at this it might help to get the current or next/previous viewcontroller from `pendingViewControllers` array.

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: So if the page view controller is displaying only one view controller, is there going to be only one view controller in the `pendingViewControllers` array?

Comment: It should have. I never faced that case but the answer should be YES.

Comment: Thank you! This workaround works perfect for my case. I'd like to submit a bug report to apple since I didn't see the issue being mentioned in their known issue list.

Comment: One problem though: the `willTransitionToViewControllers` method is not called when the initial scene is loaded, so the texts are not displayed for the first text view. I've tried to set up the text view for the initial scene in `viewDidLoad` but it does not work. Any idea how to deal with this corner case?

Comment: NVM, I figured out how to make it work. I originally set the text view of the content controller before setting the content controller to be contained in the page view controller. I just switched the order and it works by magic.

Comment: How did you make it work also share this this might help others.

Answer (score 7):

Solution to this problem in **Swift**:

I encountered the bug when I used more than 3 `UIPageViewController` (try with 4 `UIPageViewController` for example, using the @Rashad's snippet). The problem came from a missing and non implemented optional UIPageViewControllerDelegate's method, which drove the UIPageControl crazy and unstable.

Please find the particular method which fixes the bug below:

```
/*
    Optional UIPageViewControllerDelegate method

    Sent when a gesture-initiated transition ends. The 'finished' parameter indicates whether
    the animation finished, while the 'completed' parameter indicates whether the transition completed or bailed out (if the user let go early).
*/
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
    didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
    previousViewControllers: [AnyObject],
    transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
{
    // Turn is either finished or aborted
    if (completed && finished) {
        let currentDisplayedViewController = self.pageViewController!.viewControllers[0] as! ContentViewController
        self.pageControl.currentPage = currentDisplayedViewController.index
    }
}
```

If you want to get the full working project, please find the Github link below:

([Github link of the project](https://github.com/King-Wizard/Swift-Spotify-Like-Carousel))

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem like this function is getting called...any idea why not?

Comment: Check the github project mentioned in the answer, download it and try to run it and read the source code. Then duplicate my source code and adapt it for your needs. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been slaving on this issue for days; works like a charm now!

Answer (score 1):

So as @Rashad suggested, `pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:` isn't messed up. It is called exactly once when you transition to the previous/next view controller (in case that the previous/next view controller is not `nil`). This also applies to `pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:`, which is called exactly once when the animation finishes.

So if you want to do any index-based things and you want to get the correct index for the upcoming view controllers, or you want to get the correct view controller, consider using these two methods as a workaround for now.

Comment: How exactly do I get the index from this method? please help

Answer (score 1):

change the transition style from scroll to pageCurl

pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .pageCurl, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)

it's look better and it will not called twice